# Errors upgrading cordova app

Tags: java, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm trying to update a phonegap Android app from cordova 3.5.0 to cordova 5.1.1 because of security concerns.
When I launch the app I get the following errors but I just can't understand where they come from.. Could you help me by suggesting where to investigate?

```
W/System.err( 1672): org.json.JSONException: Value PluginManager at 0 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to int
W/System.err( 1672):    at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:100)
W/System.err( 1672):    at org.json.JSONArray.getInt(JSONArray.java:357)
W/System.err( 1672):    at org.apache.cordova.CordovaBridge.promptOnJsPrompt(CordovaBridge.java:131)
W/System.err( 1672):    at org.apache.cordova.engine.SystemWebChromeClient.onJsPrompt(SystemWebChromeClient.java:119)
W/System.err( 1672):    at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.handleMessage(CallbackProxy.java:655)
W/System.err( 1672):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
W/System.err( 1672):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
W/System.err( 1672):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
W/System.err( 1672):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/System.err( 1672):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
W/System.err( 1672):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
W/System.err( 1672):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
W/System.err( 1672):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
W/System.err( 1672): org.json.JSONException: Value App at 0 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to int
W/System.err( 1672):    at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:100)
W/System.err( 1672):    at org.json.JSONArray.getInt(JSONArray.java:357)
W/System.err( 1672):    at org.apache.cordova.CordovaBridge.promptOnJsPrompt(CordovaBridge.java:131)
W/System.err( 1672):    at org.apache.cordova.engine.SystemWebChromeClient.onJsPrompt(SystemWebChromeClient.java:119)
W/System.err( 1672):    at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.handleMessage(CallbackProxy.java:655)
W/System.err( 1672):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
W/System.err( 1672):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
W/System.err( 1672):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
W/System.err( 1672):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/System.err( 1672):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
W/System.err( 1672):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
W/System.err( 1672):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
W/System.err( 1672):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
W/System.err( 1672): org.json.JSONException: Value File at 0 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to int
W/System.err( 1672):    at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:100)
W/System.err( 1672):    at org.json.JSONArray.getInt(JSONArray.java:357)
W/System.err( 1672):    at org.apache.cordova.CordovaBridge.promptOnJsPrompt(CordovaBridge.java:131)
W/System.err( 1672):    at org.apache.cordova.engine.SystemWebChromeClient.onJsPrompt(SystemWebChromeClient.java:119)
W/System.err( 1672):    at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.handleMessage(CallbackProxy.java:655)
W/System.err( 1672):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
W/System.err( 1672):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
W/System.err( 1672):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
W/System.err( 1672):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/System.err( 1672):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
W/System.err( 1672):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
W/System.err( 1672):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
W/System.err( 1672):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Do you have the latests SDK versions (22 i think) ?

Comment: I'm not sure, but sometimes, removing the plugins and re-add them regenerates the code finely. Hope it's just this for you.

Comment: @jcesarmobile npm update -g and then I changed phonegap version in config.xml

Comment: @LeZohan68 just tried but didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Edit: I haden't gone through all the coments of the other answer and I now realize this answer may not be really usefull to the OP, but anyway it may help someone fighting with Cordova 3.x->5 migration...

When you update cordova you often have to also update the platform and the plugins.

So after you upgraded the CLI like you did, you have to remove all platforms and plugins then re-install it.

(if you have content that is only in the platform think to save it before)

Before we start, save the list of the plugins you use

```
cordova plugin list
```

Then we clean everything (windows command prompt):

```
rd /s/q platforms
rd /s /q plugins
```

or for linux/OS X :

```
rm -rf platforms
rm -rf plugins
```

please note that it is a kind of "brute" way to remove platforms and plugins, you could just run `cordova platform remove android` but then you would have to deal with the file platforms.json and you could use `cordova plugin remove ...` for each plugin but it would be longer.

Then you use `cordova plugin add ...` to re-add all your plugins.

Be carefull, the core plugins in cordova 5 are now using npm instead of git, so for each plugin you have to check the new id or you may get the old versions.

For ex, use

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera
```

instead of

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.camera
```

And finally you have to add the new plugin responsible for the security

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist
```

And configure it in config.xml and add a CSP meta tag in your html.

And re-add the platform :

```
cordova plugin add android
```

Comment: In which SO should this work? del isn't a command on mac os X

Comment: I saw no OS specified in the question, so I went for what is the most common : Windows. In OS X, should type rm -r instead of del (but actually, even for windows, del is not the best command to use)

Answer (score 4):

To update a cordova project you have to do this:

First update the CLI version with

```
npm update -g cordova
```

then go to your project folder and do

```
cordova platform update android
```

Comment: I'm sorry but after doing what you said the errors are exactly the same :(

Comment: ehm I think not. anyway currently I've removed every plugin-

Comment: and if you add them again the problem persists? Do you have the same problem if you create a new empty project? Do you have java 7 or java 8 installed?

Comment: yes, it persists if I add them again.
no, a fresh new app runs ok. (but it would be a bit challenging to move the entire app to a new project - please help me :|

Comment: the problem persists even moving the app to a new project! [quite desperate now]

Comment: which java version are you using? try with java 7

Comment: so, if you are using java 7 and the problem persist even if you create a new project, the problem should be on your code, can you provide it?

Comment: That is not code from a typical phonegap project, you have edited the MainActivity with your own code, so I don't think this is a cordova problem. You should have mentioned all this on your question. To fix it, you will have to debug the app using breakpoints

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you had 'partially upgraded' you project. I would recommend to start with a fresh 5.11 Cordova project and build it the same you did with the original 3.5.0 project.

Try to automate (as in script) the process of building your project such that you can always start with a fresh Cordova project and auto build it to become your full blown app.

I have used that option in the past to overcome some unexplained issues - all due to upgrades not being as smooth as they should be.